# Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?

Tags: qt

Cuando compilo un ejemplo de Qt me aparece este mensaje y no se solucionarlo:

> ```
> Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
> 15:22:23: The process "C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 3.
> Error while building/deploying project mapviewer (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MinGW 32bit)
> When executing step "qmake"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no has instalado el compilador de c++ ( `g++` ) o al menos no lo tienes en la ruta `PATH` que es donde se sacan los ejecutables que puedes usar desde cualquier lugar. Lo mas probable es que estes usando windows pues en linux/unix esto se hace automaticamente. Si has instalado gcc ( GNU compiler collection que debe incluir g++) lo que tienes que hacer es asignarle a `PATH` la ruta donde se encuentra el compilardor g++. Si no lo has instalado lo que tienes que hacer es descargarlo e instalarlo. Puedes comprobar en cualquier momento si lo tienes instalado y en la variable de entorno PATH con escribir en la consola: `g++ --version`. te debe salir algo como esto:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Como veo de tu pregunta veo que tienes instalado mingw , que debe ser lo que te instala por defecto qt. Asi que lo que debes hacer es buscar en la carpeta bin que debe estar dentro de `mingw` por el compilador g++ y asignarle a PATH la ruta de donde lo encuentre. Revisa bien puede que no este en la misma carpeta bin donde estaba qmake sino en otra bin